# Will the gradle `force` specified in a lib override the app's dependency at runtime

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

On Android and having a library (call it `com.group.one:lib_A`);

and a library `com.group.other:lib_b` and lib module `com.group.other:lib_c`.
The `lib_B` has dependency on `lib_C`

```
lib_B version 3.0.0 depends on lib_C 3.0.0

lib_B version 3.1.0 depends on lib_C 3.1.0
```

The `lib_A` has dependency on `lib_B`. Since `lib_A` depends one some other libs that may also depend on `lib_B`, or `lib_C`, the `lib_A` would like to force to use the same version 3.1.0 on both `lib_B` and `lib_C`, which are built with this version of the `lib_A` i.e `lib_A:8.0.0`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.group.other:lib_B:3.1.0"
    ... ...
}
   
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested

        // force all the flurry modules to same version
        if (requested.group == 'com.group.one') {
            details.useVersion "3.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

And there is app which depends on `lib_A:8.0.0` and `lib_B:3.0.0`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.group.one:lib_A:8.0.0"
    implementation "com.group.other:lib_B:3.0.0"
}
```

When runs the app, what would be the version of `lib_b` and `lib_c` to be used? the 3.1.0`or`3.0.0`?